# How do I make my JavaScript loop run slower

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying a little bit of coding and I would like for the 30 character strings to appear in the 1 second intervals one after another when the code is started. I tried setInterval & setTimeout and I couldn't get it to work. If someone could please help that would be much appreciated.

```
count = 0
while (count < 200) {
    console.log(create_random_string(30))

function create_random_string(string_length){
    var random_string = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for(var i, i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
        random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    }
    return  "|BTC| " + random_string +  "  | " + " PRIVATNI KLJUČ NIJE ISPRAVAN" + "  | " + " STANJE: 0.00"
}
count = count + 1
}
```

Comment: The Java script is not equal to javascript.

Comment: Declaring a `var` inside a function means the variable is created and destroyed each time the function runs. Using setInterval means a function provided by you runs every X milliseconds. The string variable you want to build has to be declared outside that function or everything starts over again each time.

Comment: answered the question, welcome to StackOverflow, if the answer is good, don't forget to designate it as the "accepted answer" and upvote it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(code, time);
```

this function will allow you to wait X miliseconds before running the code defined.

here, the correct code, and i fixed your formatting a bit.

```
let count = 0;
while (count < 200) {
    setTimeout(
        function() { console.log(create_random_string(30)); }
        , 500);
    count++;
}

function create_random_string(string_length){
    var random_string = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for(var i, i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
        random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    }
    return  "|BTC| " + random_string +  "  | " + " PRIVATNI KLJUČ NIJE ISPRAVAN" + "  | " + " STANJE: 0.00"
}
```

by the way, you probably wanted to replace `characters.length` inside your for loop for : string_length to use the fuction's parameter (which you never actually used)

Comment: I get an error when I run your code, https://prnt.sc/YBeHZj4sovLy, no idea what to do, it only displays one 30 character string and then it gives an error. I want it to display 200 30 character strings in the intervals of 1 second between each

Comment: "callback must be a function" means you needed to surround your console.log(create_random_string(30)) in a function. I updated the code for you.